# Directory: giving full control in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code in C# for giving full control to any file, it works excellent.

But how can I give full control to any directory?

Code to give full access to a file:

```
string fileName = @"d:\MyFile.mdb";
FileSecurity fSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(fileName);
fSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
File.SetAccessControl(fileName, fSecurity);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944765/c-sharp-set-directory-permissions-for-all-users-in-windows-7

Answer (score 3):

In exactly the same way, but using `Directory.GetAccessControl` instead of `File.GetAccessControl`:

```
DirectorySecurity dirSec = Directory.GetAccessControl("C:\\temp");
dirSec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
Directory.SetAccessControl("c:\\temp", dirSec);
```

Comment: i try this on C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWS  it adds the Everyone user but no full control , what can be the problem ?

Comment: You're launching program not as Administrator?

Comment: i think that i Administrator, but if not - is there any way to run the program as Administrator ?

Comment: Getting closer.  now added the "Everyone" group to the folder, but the permissions show up blank; nothing granted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
        DirectoryInfo myDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Dir1\");

        DirectorySecurity myDirectorySecurity = myDirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl();

        string User = System.Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + "Everyone"; 

        myDirectorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(User, 
                                          FileSystemRights.FullControl, 
                                          AccessControlType.Deny)); 

        myDirectoryInfo.SetAccessControl(myDirectorySecurity);
```