# Remove all directory permissions & set new permissions using C#

Tags: c#, security, file-permissions, folder-permissions

I want to remove previously set directory permissions to a folder & set new permissions as per requirement.

I have referred this link
[Remove All Directory Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445388/remove-all-directory-permissions)

but once i removed all permission it never allows me to set new rules.

my code

```
 DirectoryInfo myDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\Shared\\Testing");
                DirectorySecurity myDirectorySecurity = myDirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
                string User = System.Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Convert.ToString(dt_UserDetails.Rows[i]["AD_NAME"]);

                AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = myDirectorySecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));

                myDirectorySecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, false);

                if (Convert.ToInt16(dt_UserDetails.Rows[i]["ACCESS_CONTROL_TYPE"]) == 1)
                {
                    new FileSystemAccessRule(User, FileSystemRights.ChangePermissions, AccessControlType.Allow);

                }
                else if (Convert.ToInt16(dt_UserDetails.Rows[i]["ACCESS_CONTROL_TYPE"]) == 0)
                {
                    new FileSystemAccessRule(User, FileSystemRights.ChangePermissions, AccessControlType.Deny);                    
                }

                myDirectoryInfo.SetAccessControl(myDirectorySecurity);
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: can u show your code please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically Adding Permissions to a Folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478917/programmatically-adding-permissions-to-a-folder)

Comment: when first time I run this it works but second times it wont work

Comment: @EhsanSajjad i have tried that code already. but if i remove all permissions and try to set new then I'm unable to do it

Comment: Well, if you remove all permissions then the code itself no longer has permission to change permissions... so this behaviour is correct. You have to leave the permission that allows your code to alter the other permissions intact while it's running.

Comment: is there any way to achieve it?