# C# - Show "Get file permission" dialog to get access

Tags: c#, .net, permissions

I want to be able to have my user get read/write privileges to folders that they don't have access to without them having to do extra work. I'd like for the box to appear below, then they can simply hit "continue", then the program will progress.

I'm able to make the box appear by using

```
Process.Start(filePath);
```

but then that also opens the folder, which is a bit clunky. Is there a way to just show this dialog, wait for the user to interact, then continue execution?

[image]

Comment: is this code executed as performing user?
do you want to perform this in background? - just set permissions?

Comment: @profesor79 - If I could do it in the background that would be great, still trying to look up how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What I will do in this case:

test permission on file, you can add what ever is needed (read, execute, traverse)

```
public static bool HasWritePermissionOnDir(string path)
{
    var writeAllow = false;
    var writeDeny = false;
    var accessControlList = Directory.GetAccessControl(path);
    if (accessControlList == null)
        return false;
    var accessRules = accessControlList.GetAccessRules(true, true, 
                                typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier));
    if (accessRules ==null)
        return false;

    foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in accessRules)
    {
        if ((FileSystemRights.Write & rule.FileSystemRights) != FileSystemRights.Write) 
            continue;

        if (rule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Allow)
            writeAllow = true;
        else if (rule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Deny)
            writeDeny = true;
    }

    return writeAllow && !writeDeny;
}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1281638/5919473)

then if there is no access

```
// Add the access control entry to the file.
AddFileSecurity(fileName, @"DomainName\AccountName",
                FileSystemRights.ReadData, AccessControlType.Allow);
```

> FileSystemRights - set as needed [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)

Put all operations in try-catch blocks as dealing with files are always gona to have issues :-)

Ensure that you user has a privilege to change permissions (run as Admin)

Comment: Hm, I've tried this, and I've also the code at the following thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944765/c-sharp-set-directory-permissions-for-all-users-in-windows-7

And like that guy, I'm not having any luck. The code completes successfully, but the rights aren't given as expected.