# In which cases DirectorySecurity.ModifyAccessRule returns false?

Tags: c#, windows, acl

We found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944765/c-sharp-set-directory-permissions-for-all-users-in-windows-7) the next snippet of code:

```
bool Result = false;
Security.ModifyAccessRule(AccessControlModification.Set, AccessRule, out Result);

if (!Result)
    return false;
```

In which exact cases "Result" is going to be false? Does anyone know? Please, help us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs, the result of `Security.ModifyAccessRule` would be `true` if the DACL is successfully modified; otherwise, `false`

See the following for reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.modifyaccessrule?view=netframework-4.7.2