# How to create a directory in which only Administrator has full control?

Tags: c#

I've created in C# a program which creates a directory and some files inside it.

How can I set (programmatically - if possible) the *Full-Control* right only for *Administrator*? The *ideal* case would be to inhibit the *Write* and *Read* rights for a *non-administrator* user (creating a "kind of hidden folder"), but it would also be enough for me to set only the Read right for a *non-administrator* user, stop.

I've  tried to search in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), but nobody has written about the same problem. Inf act, everybody talks about "all users". Me no.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944765/c-sharp-set-directory-permissions-for-all-users-in-windows-7

Comment: @CodeCaster **out of place**. The question is different.

Comment: What do you mean by "out of place"? But alright, let me rephrase: please read [ask] and show what you have tried. Searching the web for "C# set directory access control permissions" yields plenty of results. Perhaps no single example will match your exact requirements, but I assume you're able to replace something like `WellKnownSidType.BuiltinUsersSid` with `WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, it's possible. First, you have to create the directory then set it's access rules.

```cs
var directory = Directory.CreateDirectory("SomeFolder");

var directorySecurity = directory.GetAccessControl();

var administratorRule = new FileSystemAccessRule("Administrators", FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow);
var usersRole = new FileSystemAccessRule("Users", FileSystemRights.CreateDirectories | FileSystemRights.CreateFiles, AccessControlType.Allow);

directorySecurity.AddAccessRule(administratorRule);
directorySecurity.AddAccessRule(usersRole);

directory.SetAccessControl(directorySecurity);
```